# Decimal to integer conversion error

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a school project using VIsual Studio 2015, the assignment is to create GUI "Commute Calculator" with three options for mode of transportation. I've wrote the code following the instructions in my textbook but am getting the following error:

> "*BC30057  Too many arguments to 'Private Function CarFindCost(intCommuteChoice As Integer, intDays As Integer) As Decimal*'."

I'm a newbie to vs, but based on the error I believe the problem is with how I declared variables. I googled how to convert an integer to decimal, but haven't found anything that worked. The code is lengthy, but I included it all as an FYI. The error is in the private sub btnCommute and appears to be tied to three private functions: CarFindCost, BusFindCost and TrainFindCost. How to I fix it so I don't get errors on the variable intLength in the private sub bthCommute?

```
Option Strict On

Public Class frmCommuteCalc
    Dim intCommuteChoice As Integer
    Dim strSelectedMode As String = ""
    Private _strGas As Integer
    Private _strMiles As String = "Enter the total miles for a round trip: "
    Private _strMilesPerGallon As Double = 2.15
    Private _strDailyParking As Decimal = 10
    Private _strMonthlyParking As Decimal
    Private _strMonthlyUpkeep As Decimal = 112
    Private _strRTBusFare As String = "Round trip bus fare is "
    Private _strRTTrainFare As String = "Round trip train fare is "
    Private _StrDays As String = "Enter the number of days worked per month: "
    Private _intTrainFare As Integer


    Private Sub frmCommuteCalc_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)

    End Sub

    Private Sub cboCommuteMethod_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboCommuteMethod.SelectedIndexChanged

        Dim intCommuteChoice As Integer

        intCommuteChoice = cboCommuteMethod.SelectedIndex()
        lstCommute.Items.Clear()

        Select Case intCommuteChoice
            Case 0
                Car()
            Case 1
                Train()
            Case 2
                Bus()
        End Select

        lblDays.Visible = True
        lblMiles.Visible = True
        lblLength.Visible = True
        txtDays.Visible = True
        'txtMonthlyTotal.Visible = True


    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCompute_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCompute.Click

        Dim intCommuteChoice As Integer
        Dim intDaysPerMonth As Integer
        Dim decTotalCost As Decimal
        Dim intLength As Integer = 0
        Dim strSelectedMode As String = ""
        Dim blnNumberInDaysIsValid As Boolean = False
        Dim blnCommuteMethodIsSelected As Boolean = False

        blnNumberInDaysIsValid = ValidateNumberInDays()

        intCommuteChoice = ValidateCommuteSelection(blnCommuteMethodIsSelected, strSelectedMode)

        If (blnNumberInDaysIsValid And blnCommuteMethodIsSelected) Then
            intDaysPerMonth = Convert.ToInt32(txtDays.Text)
            intCommuteChoice = cboCommuteMethod.SelectedIndex()
            Select Case intCommuteChoice
                Case 0
                    decTotalCost = CarFindCost(intCommuteChoice, intDaysPerMonth, intLength)
                Case 1
                    decTotalCost = BusFindCost(intCommuteChoice, intDaysPerMonth, intLength)
                Case 2
                    decTotalCost = TrainFindCost(intCommuteChoice, intDaysPerMonth, intLength)
            End Select

        End If



    End Sub

    Private Function intLength() As Object
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Function

    Function ComputeCommuteCost(ByVal decMiles As Decimal, ByVal decGallons As Decimal) As Decimal

        Dim decMilage As Decimal

        decMilage = decMiles / decGallons
        Return decMilage

    End Function
    Private Sub Car()

        lstCommute.Items.Add(_strMiles)
        lstCommute.Items.Add(_strMilesPerGallon)
        lstCommute.Items.Add(_StrDays)
        lstCommute.Items.Add(_strMonthlyParking)
        lstCommute.Items.Add(_strMonthlyUpkeep)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Bus()

        lstCommute.Items.Add(_strRTBusFare)
        lstCommute.Items.Add(_StrDays)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Train()
        lstCommute.Items.Add(_StrDays)
        lstCommute.Items.Add(_strRTTrainFare)

    End Sub
    Private Function ValidateNumberInDays() As Boolean

        Dim intDays As Integer
        Dim blnValidityCheck As Boolean = False
        Dim strNumberInDaysMessage As String = "Please enter the No. of days per month you will be commuting "
        Dim strMessageBoxTitle As String = "Error"

        Try
            intDays = Convert.ToInt32(txtDays.Text)
            If intDays >= 1 And intDays <= 21 Then
                blnValidityCheck = True
            Else
                MsgBox(strNumberInDaysMessage, , strMessageBoxTitle)
                txtDays.Focus()
                txtDays.Clear()
            End If
        Catch Exception As FormatException
            MsgBox(strNumberInDaysMessage, , strMessageBoxTitle)
            txtDays.Focus()
            txtDays.Clear()
        Catch Exception As OverflowException
            MsgBox(strNumberInDaysMessage, , strMessageBoxTitle)
            txtDays.Focus()
            txtDays.Clear()
        Catch Exception As SystemException
            MsgBox(strNumberInDaysMessage, , strMessageBoxTitle)
            txtDays.Focus()
            txtDays.Clear()
        End Try

        Return blnValidityCheck

    End Function

    Private Function ValidateCommuteSelection(ByRef blnDays As Boolean, ByRef strDays As String) As Integer
        Dim intCommuteChoice As Integer

        Try
            intCommuteChoice = Convert.ToInt32(lstCommute.SelectedIndex)
            strDays = lstCommute.SelectedItem.ToString()
            blnDays = True
        Catch Exception As SystemException
            MsgBox("Select a commute mode", , "Error")
            blnDays = False
        End Try

        Return intCommuteChoice

    End Function

    Private Function CarFindCost(ByVal intCommuteChoice As Integer, ByVal intDays As Integer) As Decimal
        Dim decDaysPerMonth As Decimal
        Dim decMiles As Decimal
        Dim decMilesPerGallon As Decimal = 2
        Dim decGasTotal As Decimal
        Dim decDailyParking As Decimal = 10
        Dim decMonthlyParking As Decimal
        Dim decMonthlyUpkeep As Decimal = 112
        Dim decFinalCost As Decimal
        Dim intLength As Integer = 0

        decMiles = Convert.ToDecimal(txtMiles.Text)
        decMilesPerGallon = Convert.ToDecimal(txtGallons.Text)
        decGasTotal = decMilesPerGallon * decMiles
        decMonthlyParking = Convert.ToDecimal(lblLength.Text)
        decMonthlyParking = decDailyParking * decDaysPerMonth
        decFinalCost = Convert.ToDecimal(lblLength.Text)
        decFinalCost = decGasTotal + decMonthlyUpkeep + decMonthlyParking

        Return decFinalCost

    End Function

    Private Function BusFindCost(ByVal intCommuteChoice As Integer, ByVal intDays As Integer) As Decimal

        Dim intLength As Integer = 0
        Dim decDaysPerMonth As Decimal
        Dim decBusFarePerDay As Decimal = 4
        Dim decFinalCost As Decimal

        decBusFarePerDay = Convert.ToDecimal(txtMonthlyTotal)
        decFinalCost = decBusFarePerDay * decDaysPerMonth

        Return decFinalCost

    End Function

    Private Function TrainFindCost(ByVal intCommuteChoice As Integer, ByVal intDays As Integer) As Decimal

        Dim intLength As Integer = 0
        Dim decDaysPerMonth As Decimal
        Dim decTrainFarePerDay As Decimal = 18
        Dim decFinalCost As Decimal

        decTrainFarePerDay = Convert.ToDecimal(txtMonthlyTotal)
        decFinalCost = Convert.ToDecimal(txtMonthlyTotal)
        decFinalCost = decDaysPerMonth * decTrainFarePerDay

        Return decFinalCost

    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: You've posted 215 lines of code. You're getting compiler error in 1. And it's is not an error converting decimal to integer.

Comment: You’re passing 3 arguments (`intLength` is the third) to a function that only expects 2 arguments.

Comment: @abatishchev. Why bother commenting if you don't have anything helpful to say. I'm new to this, and asking for help, a little compassion would have been nice instead of criticism. Please feel free to block me if stack overflow has this option.

Comment: On one had I'm sorry you to face unpleasant comments to your first question. On other - I don't see you read the compiler error you received, neither tried to make your question readable.

Comment: @lorac1969 they're constructive and useful comments. Read the rules of the site, abide by them and everything will work out just fine. Only post _relevant_ code. If it doesn't appear you've made the effort, you'll get called out for it.

Comment: We need a `PEBCAK / PEBKAC` close reason

Comment: @Yatrix This site is filled with people who are quick to criticize without offering helpful advice. I posted all of the code because when I had a previous question and only posted some of the code, people chastized me for not posting enough of the code. As I mentioned I am new to this, people like you don't seem to remember what that was like. You have so much to learn you don't necessarily know the right questions to ask or what the relevant code is. It would be better to help rather than intimidate someone asking for help.

Comment: @lorac1969 I do remember what it was like. I'd mess up, people would point it out in the same manner, then I'd handle myself like an adult and fix the issue. I've had questions down-voted and closed, so I figured out the right way to do it.

If you don't know what the relevant code is, you haven't done enough to ask the question. I understand you're inexperienced, but it's _your responsibility_ to gain that experience.

So, stop complaining and just deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

In:

```
Select Case intCommuteChoice ... End Select
```

in each `case`; call function `CarFindCost` with 3 parameters y you have declared with only 2.

Comment: Hi Roberto, thanks so much for pointing me in the right direction. It can be intimidating dealing with techies you know are much better at this than you are, so thanks again.

Comment: @lorac1969 if this answered your question, please **upvote and accept** this answer. If it didn't solve your issue, but you found it helpful, please **upvote** the answer.